# Reading file from Azure Data Lake Storage V2 with Spark 2.4

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to read a simple csv file Azure Data Lake Storage V2 with Spark 2.4 on my IntelliJ-IDE on mac

Code Below

```
package com.example

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._



object Test extends App {

  val appName: String = "DataExtract"
  val master: String = "local[*]"
  val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName(appName)
    .setMaster(master)
    .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
    .set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
    .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "32")
    .set("fs.defaultFS", "abfs://development@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/")
    .set("fs.azure.account.key.xyz.dfs.core.windows.net", "~~key~~")


  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .getOrCreate()
  spark.time(run(spark))


def run(spark: SparkSession): Unit = {

  val df = spark.read.csv("abfs://development@xyz.dfs.core.windows.net/development/sales.csv")
  df.show(10)

}

}
```

It's able to read, and throwing security exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wildfly.openssl.CipherSuiteConverter.toJava(CipherSuiteConverter.java:284)
    at org.wildfly.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.toJavaCipherSuite(OpenSSLEngine.java:1094)
    at org.wildfly.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.getEnabledCipherSuites(OpenSSLEngine.java:729)
    at org.wildfly.openssl.OpenSSLContextSPI.getCiphers(OpenSSLContextSPI.java:333)
    at org.wildfly.openssl.OpenSSLContextSPI$1.getSupportedCipherSuites(OpenSSLContextSPI.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.utils.SSLSocketFactoryEx.<init>(SSLSocketFactoryEx.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.utils.SSLSocketFactoryEx.initializeDefaultFactory(SSLSocketFactoryEx.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.<init>(AbfsClient.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.initializeClient(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:108)
```

Can anyone help me, what is the mistake?

Comment: Hi Sandeep540,If the answer is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my research, you will receive this error message when you have incompatible jar with the hadoop version.

I would request you to kindly go through the below issues:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201907.mbox/%3CJIRA.13243325.1562321895000.591499.1562323440292@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16410

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, resolved by adding wildfly version 1.0.7, as the docs shared by @cheekatlapradeep-msft mentioned

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wildfly.openssl</groupId>
  <artifactId>wildfly-openssl</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```